# The way to create abstract enum

Tags: java, enums

I have some enums, which has `getDescription()` method:

```
public enum Test {
    QWE ("qwe"),
    ASD ("asd"),
    ZXC ("zxc");

    private final String description;

    Test(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}

public enum Test1 {
    RTY("rty");

    private final String description;

    Test1(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to create some abstract enum or some interface, that it could be write something like this?

```
public void outputDescriptions(AbstractEnumType abstractEnumType) {
    for(Enum enum: abstractEnumType.values()) {
        System.out.println(enum.getDescription());
    }
}
```

And output for `outputDescriptions(Test)`

```
qwe
asd
zxc
```

Comment: What kept you from trying?

Comment: Well, `enums` can't extend classes but they **can** implement interfaces...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot derive enums from an abstract base class but enums can implement interfaces. The following would be a solution to your problem:

You create an interface `Descriptable`

```
 public interface Descriptable {
      public String getDescription();
 }
```

and let all your enums implement this interface:

```
 public enum Test implements Descriptable {
```

and then write the output function like this:

```
public <T extends Enum<T> & Descriptable> void outputDescriptions(Class<T> tclass) {
    for(T t: tclass.getEnumConstants())
        System.out.println(t.getDescription());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Enums can implement interfaces:

```
interface Descr {
    String getDescription();
}

enum Test implements Descr {
    QWE ("qwe"),
    ASD ("asd"),
    ZXC ("zxc");
    private final String description;
    Test(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, define interface with desired method

```
interface DescriptionableEnum {
  String getDescription();
}
```

Next, add to all your enums implementation of this interafce:

```
enum Test implements DescriptionableEnum {...}
enum Test1 implements DescriptionableEnum {...}
```

And this function will help you:

```
public static void outputDescriptions(Class<? extends DescriptionableEnum> abstractEnumType) {
    if (abstractEnumType.isEnum()) {
        DescriptionableEnum[] values = abstractEnumType.getEnumConstants();
        for (DescriptionableEnum value : values) {
            System.out.println(value.getDescription());
        }
    }
}
```

Main method for testing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    outputDescriptions(Test.class);
    outputDescriptions(Test1.class);
}
```

Comment: ok, but how can get DescriptionableEnum name like in enum?
`value` doesn't has `name()` method.

Comment: You can just add abstract method name() in interface:

    
    interface DescriptionableEnum {
        String name();
        String getDescription();
    }

Comment: @qweasd: or you make sure that the objects in the loop are enums. See my solution.

Comment: @wero, yep that's right. the type constraints are better in your solution

Answer (score 0):

No, we can't have abstract enums, all enum types extend Enum, and they're final by default. Since Java does not support multiple inheritance, an enum cannot extend anything else.

However an enum can implement `Interface`.